# Same engine but different intake manifold design: which one should I use?

Tags: fuel-consumption, carburetor, performance, intake-manifold

The engine I'm rebuilding (Skoda Estelle '72, RWD, rear mounted engine) is the same from previous models, with slight different changes. One of the things they modified was the intake manifold which, as I'm guessing, correspond to a different carburetor being provided. I have the two kinds of those manifolds, but the carburetor I'm adapting comes from a classic Lada. The Lada manifold has one single slot in the carburetor seat; the manifold that came with the engine is the kind with two interconnecting "holes":

The first top pictures is the manifold that came with the engine, the picture below is the other manifold resembling very much a Lada's (from which I will use the carburetor).

My guess is that in the "holes" manifold, the top hole which has an insert ring, provides something like a pool of gas, to help the engine crank perhaps in cold Czech winters :) When I teared the engine into parts, I could see a puddle of gas there. To start this engine (which already had a Lada carburetor) I had always to kick the gas pedal a few times before running the starter.

The second manifold does not comes with the vacuum port for the brakes, but that's something I can add.

So my question is a bit complex, hopefully someone with experience could guide me:

**Is there any real benefit or not (from any angle: consumption, performance, etc) by installing the second manifold?** Besides just resembling the Lada's carburetor seat...

[image]

EDIT:

Pics of the Lada Carb against the second manifold

[image]

Comment: Is there a picture from the other side (from the side which mounts to the cylinder head)? Is the engine fed from only two ports I can see on the manifold, or is there something I don't see here?  Also, the ring which is installed in the top image, does it only extend down so far, then is open to the plenum? Is the size of the carburetor (if you can tell) any larger from the bottom manifold than from the top one? (You could measure the bore size of the carburetor to see).

Comment: Also, picture of the carb you're going to use? (Picture of the carb you're *not going to use* would be awesome as well.) I'd be wanting to see the bottom side of each with the butterfly open.

Comment: Reviewing the parts catalog I have, I see the second manifold came in older Skoda (100) and the first one in later Skoda (120x). The 120 used a Jikov carb, weber kind. I don't have pics of that but I'll post pics of the Lada one I got.

Comment: Both manifolds are almost identical, except for the carburetor seat. The ring insert is only about 1/2", and both holes connect underneath it with an opening of about 3/4". In both, the Lada carburetor sits without problems, stud holes coincides and the butterflies can fully open without touching nothing.

Answer (score 1):

So, your real question is the bold bit at the end of your explanations: **Is there any real benefit or not (from any angle: consumption, performance, etc) by installing the second manifold?**

Answer: no. They will perform the same and consume the same.

The engines concerned are built to coarse tolerances for severe weather fluctuations. Why Lada and Skoda made different intakes for the same engine? you need to find someone who was on the design team at the time for an accurate answer!

Bear in mind you're working on a Lada, not a Merc. They didn't do 'fine-tuning' on Ladas. A Czech friend of mine told me when making something, the Russians just slap a hunk of metal in and make it work, and that the German Army lost the Russian war because all their gear had to be so precise and ball-bearings and such, while the local stuff was just solid, clunky but functional.

Your manifolds are both solid and clunky. And that's OK, because both will work fine.

Comment: yes solid , clunky apt descriptive words, starts reminding me of the old lada jokes .....

Comment: Yes, was sort of wavering whether this was the time and place for some Lada humor, but the OP is working on an old-school Skoda, and the jokes just don't sound as good :D (also didn't know if I'd lose rep for poking fun)